# ServiceMetadataBehavior attribute not found WCF C++/CLI

Tags: wcf, c++-cli

I am referencing System::ServiceModel in my C++/CLI dll project (VS2012 Express). The following code fails with the following error and I can't find how to fix it.

error C2337: 'ServiceMetadataBehavior' : attribute not found

```
[System::ServiceModel::ServiceContractAttribute]
[System::ServiceModel::Description::ServiceMetadataBehavior]
public ref class PlaybackManager
{
public:
    ~PlaybackManager() { this->!PlaybackManager(); }
    !PlaybackManager() {  }

    // Playback action methods
    [System::ServiceModel::OperationContractAttribute]
    void Play();
    [System::ServiceModel::OperationContractAttribute]
    void Stop();
    [System::ServiceModel::OperationContractAttribute]
    void Pause();
    [System::ServiceModel::OperationContractAttribute]
    void Previous();
    [System::ServiceModel::OperationContractAttribute]
    void Next();
    [System::ServiceModel::OperationContractAttribute]
    void Random();
};
```

EDIT1:

The caveat to this is that it is not possible to write a wcf service entirely with code, i.e without an app.config file. While the Service has the ServiceMetadataBehavior helper to create a metadata exchange behavior implementation, there is no such thing for the Endpoint. Is this "by design"?
[How to: Publish Metadata for a Service Using Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738489.aspx)

EDIT2:

OK, so the caveat above does not seem to be, necessarily, correct. Below is the app.config representing what I am trying to do in code and I get the same error if I remove the ServiceMetatdataBehavior attribute to the endpoint class implementation.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Engine.PlaybackManager">

        <endpoint
          address="net.tcp://localhost:7008/PlaybackManager"
          binding="mexTcpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"
          />

        <endpoint
          address="net.tcp://localhost:7008/PlaybackManager"
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          contract="Engine.PlaybackManager"
          />
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The error is:

> The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list
>   of contracts implemented by the service PlaybackManager.  Add a
>   ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the
>   ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.

The problem is, if I add the ServiceMetadataBehavior attribute to the PlaybackManager class I get the original error above, that it is not recognized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I understand why nobody responded to this, "where do I begin" was the only possible response. So, in case someone falls on this with an equal amount of confusion that I had, here are some tips:

My main issue was with the mapping the xml config nomenclature (found in most examples online) with the code equivalents:

```
<services> maps to System::ServiceModel::ServiceHost
<behaviors> maps to "your instance of ServiceHost"->Description->Behaviors
<behavior> is type specific, the type being a nested element in the xml, thus:
<behavior> <serviceMetadata /> </behavior> maps to ServiceMetadataBehavior
<endpoint> maps to ServiceEndpoint
```

and finally:
the mex endpoint (the one with the ServiceMetadataBehavior added) needs it's own namespace, so add "/mex" to the end of your implementation endpoint uri address.

```
example:
implementation address = "net.tcp://localhost:5000/Engine"
mex address =            "net.tcp://localhost:5000/Engine/mex"
```

Obviously these tips are not an explanation but I hope they might help someone as confused as I was when I asked the question.